# Are unchanged ListView-Items reused when the ListView gets rebuild?

Tags: flutter, listview, riverpod

I've got a `List<Data>` which is diplayed in a `ListView` that uses Riverpod to watch any changes to the list. When I add or remove an item from that list, the `ListView` rebuilds as intended, but it appears like every `ListViewItem` and its descending widgets are rebuild - even though they show the same content as before. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final listLength = ref.watch(dataLengthProvider);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () => ref.read(dataListProvider.notifier).add(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listLength,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return MyListItem(index);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyListItem extends ConsumerWidget {
  final int index;
  const MyListItem(this.index, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final countValue =
        ref.watch(dataItemProvider(index).select((dataItem) => dataItem.value));
    return Text('Value: ${countValue.toString()}');
  }
}

// Providers -------------------------------------------------------------------

final dataListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<DataListNotifier, List<Data>>(
    (ref) => DataListNotifier());

final dataLengthProvider =
    Provider<int>((ref) => ref.watch(dataListProvider).length);

final dataItemProvider = Provider.family<Data, int>(
    (ref, index) => ref.watch(dataListProvider)[index]);

// Notifier --------------------------------------------------------------------

class DataListNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Data>> {
  DataListNotifier() : super([const Data(), const Data()]);

  void add() {
    state = [...state, const Data(value: 0)];
  }
}

// Data model ------------------------------------------------------------------

@immutable
class Data {
  final int value;

  const Data({this.value = 0});

  Data copyWith({int? newValue}) => Data(value: newValue ?? value);
}
```

Now my question: Is Flutter smart enough to automatically re-use those unchanged widgets?

If not, what can I do to avoid unneccessary builds?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with those few rebuilds

Comment: Maybe you're right. Although, my thinking is, that if I have a very dynamic (and long) list, that might change a lot because the state of the remote source changes, it might cause issues later on. So I want to make sure I set it up properly.

Comment: what do you mean by "very dynamic"? does it change 100s per second? if your data changes once a second (or half a second) just leave it as it is, for more check https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-dont-fear-the-garbage-collector-d69b3ff1ca30

Comment: It might acutally change multiple times per second yes. I'll probably just try it for now and if it works: great!.
But I'd be curious anyhow about the answer to "Is Flutter smart enough to automatically re-use those unchanged widgets?".

Comment: every `RenderBox` is reused when you rebuild your widget, so you don't have to worry , for more check https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/inside-flutter

Comment: Thank you. I'll see where it gets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check something. To do this, remake your class `MyListItem` in to have access to dispose():

```dart
class MyListItem extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  const MyListItem(
    this.index, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState createState() => _MyListItemState();
}

class _MyListItemState extends ConsumerState<MyListItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.index);
    final countValue = ref.watch(
        dataItemProvider(widget.index).select((dataItem) => dataItem.value));
    return Text('Value: ${countValue.toString()}');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('dispose: ${widget.index}');
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

and add method `delete()` near `add()`:

```dart
void delete() {
    state.removeLast();
    state = List.of(state);
  }
```

and add button in `MyApp`:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
              child: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () => ref.read(dataListProvider.notifier).delete(),
            ),
```

And check this code again. There, of course, the `RangeError (index)` error will be raised, but this is not the point. But on the other hand, you can see that the `dispose()` method is not called when the element is added, which means that the object is not removed from the tree. At the same time, when the last element is removed, we can see the call to the `dispose()` method, but only for the last element! So you are on the right track :)

Comment: And YES, flutter is smart enough

Comment: Thank you very much for this example! Although I've probably read about this somewhere before, this helped me a lot to understand, what's actually happening.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `select` for getting the reference of the provider for stopping unnecessary rebuilds in the list item.

https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#using-select-to-filter-rebuilds

Comment: Could you elaborate? The `MyListItem` already uses `select`.